# set datetime format for specific visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, globalization

On my machine I have several visual studio projects,

if I use 
        Response.Write(Date.Now)

it will give me : 21/6/2011 2:44:49 PM  for all

except one solution it gives me: 6/21/2011 2:44:49 PM

I checked everything, all set the same:

1. Regional settings in control panel
2. `<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />`

what is wrong with that one soltion???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it,

I searched registry for yyyy,
I changed all M/d/yyyy to d/M/yyyy

it is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Well, to me a good place to start would be checking `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` static properties in the running code.

Also you can provide wider context, for example what is `Date` there it comes from, or what Response.Write code actually do.

Comment: As i said before, globalization are set correct in my project...
Response.write were for date testing purposes nothing else

Comment: Yes, they are set, but for some reason output differs, so, you need to doublecheck directly before call, to be sure and to decide what steps to do next.

Comment: please check my answer, i posted it and it fixed the issue